# Best way to store the user settings for Xamarin Application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I'm developing a client application in **Xamarin.Forms** (Android, iOS and Windows Phone) which will contact the server to get the user data. In this application i need to store the user settings like User Preferences, Server Url, UserName, authentication token . . . etc.

Can anyone suggest me a **standard** and **best** way to store the application user settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) to store the user settings as you required. This will help to access settings from shared code across all of your mobile apps.

The following code:

```
public static class Settings 
{

    private static ISettings AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return CrossSettings.Current;
        }
    }

    //Setting Constants

    const string UserName = "username";
    private static readonly string UserNameDefault = string.Empty;

    public static string UserName
    {
        get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(UserName, UserNameDefault); }
        set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(UserName, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cross Platform [Settings API](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) developed by the Xamarin Team as a Plugin:

```
public class AppPreferences
{
    static ISettings AppSettings => CrossSettings.Current;

    public static string UserName
    {
      get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(UserNameKey, UserNameDefault); }
      set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(UserNameKey, value); }
    }
}
```

Follow the link above for more info on how to add this package to your solution.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion will be SQLite, create table with user setting. SQLite is keep on phone like .txt file. You can also add more tables for other functionality.

You can always create profiles with setting and reload it.

Comment: What is the benefit of SQLite over `NSUserDefaults` and `SharedPreferences`? It seems like a heavy solution for something already easy to use in the OS, but there could be some benefits that I'm overlooking.

Comment: @dylansturg For most settings, `NSUserDefaults` and `SharedPreferences` is the way to go, but for things that, as you would expect, work better in a relation databases and might have multiple rows, are better for SQLite. For example, storing a single authentication token would work in `NSUserDefaults` and `SharedPreferences` but if, later on, you had to store multiple authentication tokens then it might make more sense to use a SQLite table (although I would still use settings for storing maybe 3 or fewer tokens, but thats just my preference).

Comment: I would discourage either option for authentication tokens - you want to store those in a secure manner (say with `KeyChain`). I see what you're saying that it's possible to have "multiple values", but I've never seen a case where my app's settings were at all relational or I needed multiple values for the same setting. Even in your scenario, you want to differentiate between the different tokens - they aren't interchangeable - so simply storing them at different keys would work. It's something to keep in mind, though.